# SQL Server 2005 not accessible

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, sql-server-2005, windows-7

I try to connect to my local installed microsoft sql server 2005.
In the firewall I allowed port 1433 for inbounding traffic. There is only the windows firewall active.

In my SQL Server, I allowed remote connections for the instance of my Server and for the SQL Browser.

When I open the console as admin and Type:

```
Sqlcmd
```

I get a message, that says: "Error establishing a connection.....allow remote connections".
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Open the **SQL Server Configuration Manager** and select your server's `Network Configuration` node.

Be sure that TCP/IP is enabled inside the protocols subnode.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the firewall is open and that sql server is running on port 1433?

Have you tried to telnet to the sql server port from your local workstation using windows command line i.e.

telnet servername|ipaddress  1433

(telnet might not be installed on your windows as default, easy to enable via windows add/remove programs.

If the telnet is successful you will get a black box with a blinking cursor, this proves that the local can connect to the server)

Comment: Yep. the firewall is deactivate. If i try the telnet command, I get this meesage: `C:\Users\Lars>telnet LARS-PC\JTLWAWI 1433
Connecting To LARS-PC\JTLWAWI...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1
433: Connect failed`

Comment: Is your machine really called LARS-PC\JTLWAWI? seems like you are putting your sql server instance into the telent.  It should be telnet <machinename> <port>